# Flutter web failing due to not supported dependencies

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies, flutter-web

I am trying to build web dev for flutter.

Dependencies are preventing me to create the app.

How can I create conditions to enable the web development of the app?

````
webdev could not run for this project.
The `build_web_compilers` version – 1.2.3 – is not within the allowed constraint – >=2.6.1 <3.0.0.
You have a dependency on `cloud_firestore` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
You have a dependency on `cupertino_icons` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
You have a dependency on `firebase_auth` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
You have a dependency on `firebase_core` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
You have a dependency on `flutter` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
You have a dependency on `flutter_test` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
You have a dependency on `image_picker` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
You have a dependency on `path_provider` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
You have a dependency on `shared_preferences` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
You have a dependency on `url_launcher` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
pub finished with exit code 78

User@DESKTOP-9470-17 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Coding Updated/Single Admin/Version Feb 21/grocery_store_admin
/flutter.dev/web for more details.
You have a dependency on `flutter_test` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
You have a dependency on `image_picker` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
You have a dependency on `path_provider` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
You have a dependency on `shared_preferences` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
You have a dependency on `url_launcher` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.```
````

Answer (score -1):

As you can see here https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web

Try to run:

```
$ flutter channel stable
$ flutter upgrade
```

but be carefull running flutter channel stable replaces your current version of Flutter with the stable version and can take time if your connection is slow. After this, running flutter upgrade upgrades your install to the latest stable. Returning to another channel (beta, dev, or master) requires calling flutter channel  explicitly.

Comment: same results with issue with SDK

Comment: I see, try deleting your .dart_tool directory. Rerun pub get and then build

Comment: flutter web does not seem to function on stable version